# Extract numbers range from string of text (character)

Tags: r

I am seeking to extract a range of numbers from a string of text in a given column.

Here is a mock dataset.

```
Meters <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21)

Miles<- c("zyx 1-2.jpg-Distance[zyx 1-2.jpg]", "zyx 15-19.jpg-Distance[zyx 15-19.jpg]", "zyx 19-23.jpg-Distance[zyx 19-23.jpg]", "zyx 24.jpg-Distance[zyx 24.jpg]", "zyx 25-28.jpg-Distance[zyx 25-28.jpg]", "zyx 29.jpg-Distance[zyx 29.jpg]", "zyx 3.jpg-Distance[zyx 3.jpg]", "zyx 30-32.jpg-Distance[zyx 30-32.jpg]", "zyx 33-36.jpg-Distance[zyx 33-36.jpg]", "zyx 37-43.jpg-Distance[zyx 37-43.jpg]", "zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]", "zyx 53-54.jpg-Distance[zyx 53-54.jpg]", "zyx 55.jpg-Distance[zyx 55.jpg]", "zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]", "zyx 6.jpg-Distance[zyx 6.jpg]", "zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]", "zyx 7-14.jpg-Distance[zyx 7-14.jpg]", "zyx 77-78.jpg-Distance[zyx 77-78.jpg]", "zyx 79-83.jpg-Distance[zyx 79-83.jpg]", "zyx1_ 4-5.jpg-Distance[zyx1_ 4-5.jpg]", "zyx2_ 4-5.jpg-Distance[zyx2_ 4-5.jpg]")

Wheels <-c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1)

Empty <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

Trip<-data.frame(Meters, Miles, Wheels, Empty)
```

What I would like to do is twofold:

One, extract only the numbers (and the hyphen between them, which I will later replace with a hyphen using `str_replace()`) from data in the "Miles" column.

Two, have these numbers represent a data range. For example, instead of "15-19" from the "zyx 15-19.jpg-Distance[zyx 15-19.jpg]", I would like "15" in one row and column, "16" in the below row, "17" in the row below, "18" in the row below, and "19" in the row below that. However, I would like the corresponding data to be kept intact alongside this change to the "Miles" column. For example, if "15-19" has "2" in the Meters column, I would like these individual new rows with "15", "16", "17", "18", and "19" in them to also have "2" in the "Meters" column, the same with the other columns and their respective values.

If I can extract only a series of numbers (e.g. "15-19") or use it to replace the ""zyx 15-19.jpg-Distance[zyx 15-19.jpg]" in the "Miles" column, I should then be able to `str_replace()` to replace the "-" with a ":" in that given column, and then

`lapply(strsplit(Trip$Miles, ":"), function(x) x[1]:x[2])`

to generate the values represented by "15:19" (15, 16, 17, 18, 19), which I can then use to create a new column.

`sub(".*.zyx ", "", x)`  should let me extract characters after a given pattern, in this case "zyx", however, I want only the numbers and the hyphen to be extracted, not anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating `seq`ences and `strsplit` using a `regexpr/regmatches` approach, then `cbind` to an `asplit` with `Map`.

```
res <- lapply(strsplit(regmatches(Trip$Miles, regexpr(r'{(?<=\s)(\d+\-\d+|\d+)}', Trip$Miles, perl=TRUE)), '-'), \(x) {
  data.frame(seq=if (length(x) == 1L) x else do.call('seq.int', as.list(as.numeric(x))))
}) |>
  Map(\(x, y) cbind(as.data.frame(t(x)), y), x=asplit(Trip, 1), y=_) |>
  do.call(what='rbind')
```

### Gives

```
res
#    Meters                                 Miles Wheels Empty seq
# 1       1     zyx 1-2.jpg-Distance[zyx 1-2.jpg]      1     0   1
# 2       1     zyx 1-2.jpg-Distance[zyx 1-2.jpg]      1     0   2
# 3       2 zyx 15-19.jpg-Distance[zyx 15-19.jpg]      2     0  15
# 4       2 zyx 15-19.jpg-Distance[zyx 15-19.jpg]      2     0  16
# 5       2 zyx 15-19.jpg-Distance[zyx 15-19.jpg]      2     0  17
# 6       2 zyx 15-19.jpg-Distance[zyx 15-19.jpg]      2     0  18
# 7       2 zyx 15-19.jpg-Distance[zyx 15-19.jpg]      2     0  19
# 8       3 zyx 19-23.jpg-Distance[zyx 19-23.jpg]      3     0  19
# 9       3 zyx 19-23.jpg-Distance[zyx 19-23.jpg]      3     0  20
# 10      3 zyx 19-23.jpg-Distance[zyx 19-23.jpg]      3     0  21
# 11      3 zyx 19-23.jpg-Distance[zyx 19-23.jpg]      3     0  22
# 12      3 zyx 19-23.jpg-Distance[zyx 19-23.jpg]      3     0  23
# 13      4       zyx 24.jpg-Distance[zyx 24.jpg]      4     0  24
# 14      5 zyx 25-28.jpg-Distance[zyx 25-28.jpg]      1     0  25
# 15      5 zyx 25-28.jpg-Distance[zyx 25-28.jpg]      1     0  26
# 16      5 zyx 25-28.jpg-Distance[zyx 25-28.jpg]      1     0  27
# 17      5 zyx 25-28.jpg-Distance[zyx 25-28.jpg]      1     0  28
# 18      6       zyx 29.jpg-Distance[zyx 29.jpg]      2     0  29
# 19      7         zyx 3.jpg-Distance[zyx 3.jpg]      3     0   3
# 20      8 zyx 30-32.jpg-Distance[zyx 30-32.jpg]      4     0  30
# 21      8 zyx 30-32.jpg-Distance[zyx 30-32.jpg]      4     0  31
# 22      8 zyx 30-32.jpg-Distance[zyx 30-32.jpg]      4     0  32
# 23      9 zyx 33-36.jpg-Distance[zyx 33-36.jpg]      1     0  33
# 24      9 zyx 33-36.jpg-Distance[zyx 33-36.jpg]      1     0  34
# 25      9 zyx 33-36.jpg-Distance[zyx 33-36.jpg]      1     0  35
# 26      9 zyx 33-36.jpg-Distance[zyx 33-36.jpg]      1     0  36
# 27     10 zyx 37-43.jpg-Distance[zyx 37-43.jpg]      2     0  37
# 28     10 zyx 37-43.jpg-Distance[zyx 37-43.jpg]      2     0  38
# 29     10 zyx 37-43.jpg-Distance[zyx 37-43.jpg]      2     0  39
# 30     10 zyx 37-43.jpg-Distance[zyx 37-43.jpg]      2     0  40
# 31     10 zyx 37-43.jpg-Distance[zyx 37-43.jpg]      2     0  41
# 32     10 zyx 37-43.jpg-Distance[zyx 37-43.jpg]      2     0  42
# 33     10 zyx 37-43.jpg-Distance[zyx 37-43.jpg]      2     0  43
# 34     11 zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]      3     0  44
# 35     11 zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]      3     0  45
# 36     11 zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]      3     0  46
# 37     11 zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]      3     0  47
# 38     11 zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]      3     0  48
# 39     11 zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]      3     0  49
# 40     11 zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]      3     0  50
# 41     11 zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]      3     0  51
# 42     11 zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]      3     0  52
# 43     12 zyx 53-54.jpg-Distance[zyx 53-54.jpg]      4     0  53
# 44     12 zyx 53-54.jpg-Distance[zyx 53-54.jpg]      4     0  54
# 45     13       zyx 55.jpg-Distance[zyx 55.jpg]      1     0  55
# 46     14 zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]      2     0  56
# 47     14 zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]      2     0  57
# 48     14 zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]      2     0  58
# 49     14 zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]      2     0  59
# 50     14 zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]      2     0  60
# 51     14 zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]      2     0  61
# 52     14 zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]      2     0  62
# 53     14 zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]      2     0  63
# 54     14 zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]      2     0  64
# 55     15         zyx 6.jpg-Distance[zyx 6.jpg]      3     0   6
# 56     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0  65
# 57     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0  66
# 58     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0  67
# 59     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0  68
# 60     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0  69
# 61     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0  70
# 62     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0  71
# 63     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0  72
# 64     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0  73
# 65     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0  74
# 66     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0  75
# 67     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0  76
# 68     17   zyx 7-14.jpg-Distance[zyx 7-14.jpg]      1     0   7
# 69     17   zyx 7-14.jpg-Distance[zyx 7-14.jpg]      1     0   8
# 70     17   zyx 7-14.jpg-Distance[zyx 7-14.jpg]      1     0   9
# 71     17   zyx 7-14.jpg-Distance[zyx 7-14.jpg]      1     0  10
# 72     17   zyx 7-14.jpg-Distance[zyx 7-14.jpg]      1     0  11
# 73     17   zyx 7-14.jpg-Distance[zyx 7-14.jpg]      1     0  12
# 74     17   zyx 7-14.jpg-Distance[zyx 7-14.jpg]      1     0  13
# 75     17   zyx 7-14.jpg-Distance[zyx 7-14.jpg]      1     0  14
# 76     18 zyx 77-78.jpg-Distance[zyx 77-78.jpg]      2     0  77
# 77     18 zyx 77-78.jpg-Distance[zyx 77-78.jpg]      2     0  78
# 78     19 zyx 79-83.jpg-Distance[zyx 79-83.jpg]      3     0  79
# 79     19 zyx 79-83.jpg-Distance[zyx 79-83.jpg]      3     0  80
# 80     19 zyx 79-83.jpg-Distance[zyx 79-83.jpg]      3     0  81
# 81     19 zyx 79-83.jpg-Distance[zyx 79-83.jpg]      3     0  82
# 82     19 zyx 79-83.jpg-Distance[zyx 79-83.jpg]      3     0  83
# 83     20 zyx1_ 4-5.jpg-Distance[zyx1_ 4-5.jpg]      4     0   4
# 84     20 zyx1_ 4-5.jpg-Distance[zyx1_ 4-5.jpg]      4     0   5
# 85     21 zyx2_ 4-5.jpg-Distance[zyx2_ 4-5.jpg]      1     0   4
# 86     21 zyx2_ 4-5.jpg-Distance[zyx2_ 4-5.jpg]      1     0   5
```

Should be about three times faster than the tidyverse solution.

---

*Data:*

```
Trip <- structure(list(Meters = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21), Miles = c("zyx 1-2.jpg-Distance[zyx 1-2.jpg]", 
"zyx 15-19.jpg-Distance[zyx 15-19.jpg]", "zyx 19-23.jpg-Distance[zyx 19-23.jpg]", 
"zyx 24.jpg-Distance[zyx 24.jpg]", "zyx 25-28.jpg-Distance[zyx 25-28.jpg]", 
"zyx 29.jpg-Distance[zyx 29.jpg]", "zyx 3.jpg-Distance[zyx 3.jpg]", 
"zyx 30-32.jpg-Distance[zyx 30-32.jpg]", "zyx 33-36.jpg-Distance[zyx 33-36.jpg]", 
"zyx 37-43.jpg-Distance[zyx 37-43.jpg]", "zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]", 
"zyx 53-54.jpg-Distance[zyx 53-54.jpg]", "zyx 55.jpg-Distance[zyx 55.jpg]", 
"zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]", "zyx 6.jpg-Distance[zyx 6.jpg]", 
"zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]", "zyx 7-14.jpg-Distance[zyx 7-14.jpg]", 
"zyx 77-78.jpg-Distance[zyx 77-78.jpg]", "zyx 79-83.jpg-Distance[zyx 79-83.jpg]", 
"zyx1_ 4-5.jpg-Distance[zyx1_ 4-5.jpg]", "zyx2_ 4-5.jpg-Distance[zyx2_ 4-5.jpg]"
), Wheels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 1), Empty = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could consider something like this :

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

Meters <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21)
Miles<- c("zyx 1-2.jpg-Distance[zyx 1-2.jpg]", "zyx 15-19.jpg-Distance[zyx 15-19.jpg]", "zyx 19-23.jpg-Distance[zyx 19-23.jpg]",
          "zyx 24.jpg-Distance[zyx 24.jpg]", "zyx 25-28.jpg-Distance[zyx 25-28.jpg]", "zyx 29.jpg-Distance[zyx 29.jpg]",
          "zyx 3.jpg-Distance[zyx 3.jpg]", "zyx 30-32.jpg-Distance[zyx 30-32.jpg]", "zyx 33-36.jpg-Distance[zyx 33-36.jpg]", 
          "zyx 37-43.jpg-Distance[zyx 37-43.jpg]", "zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]", "zyx 53-54.jpg-Distance[zyx 53-54.jpg]",
          "zyx 55.jpg-Distance[zyx 55.jpg]", "zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]", "zyx 6.jpg-Distance[zyx 6.jpg]",
          "zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]", "zyx 7-14.jpg-Distance[zyx 7-14.jpg]", "zyx 77-78.jpg-Distance[zyx 77-78.jpg]",
          "zyx 79-83.jpg-Distance[zyx 79-83.jpg]", "zyx1_ 4-5.jpg-Distance[zyx1_ 4-5.jpg]", "zyx2_ 4-5.jpg-Distance[zyx2_ 4-5.jpg]")
Wheels <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1)
Empty <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Trip <- data.frame(Meters, Miles, Wheels, Empty)
nb_Row <- nrow(Trip)

numbers_Miles <- stringr::str_extract(string = Miles, pattern = "\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2}")
bool_NA <- is.na(numbers_Miles)
numbers_Miles[bool_NA] <- stringr::str_extract(string = Miles[bool_NA], pattern = "\\d{1,2}")
list_Numbers_Miles <- list()
list_DF <- list()

for(i in 1 : nb_Row)
{
  text_Eval <- stringr::str_replace(numbers_Miles[i], "-", ":")
  list_Numbers_Miles[[i]] <- eval(parse(text = text_Eval)) 
  nb_Number <- length(list_Numbers_Miles[[i]])
  list_DF[[i]] <- Trip[rep(i, nb_Number), ]
  list_DF[[i]][["Rep_Number"]] <- list_Numbers_Miles[[i]]
}

merged_DF <- do.call(bind_rows, list_DF)
rownames(merged_DF) <- NULL

merged_DF

Meters                                 Miles Wheels Empty Rep_Number
1       1     zyx 1-2.jpg-Distance[zyx 1-2.jpg]      1     0          1
2       1     zyx 1-2.jpg-Distance[zyx 1-2.jpg]      1     0          2
3       2 zyx 15-19.jpg-Distance[zyx 15-19.jpg]      2     0         15
4       2 zyx 15-19.jpg-Distance[zyx 15-19.jpg]      2     0         16
5       2 zyx 15-19.jpg-Distance[zyx 15-19.jpg]      2     0         17
6       2 zyx 15-19.jpg-Distance[zyx 15-19.jpg]      2     0         18
7       2 zyx 15-19.jpg-Distance[zyx 15-19.jpg]      2     0         19
8       3 zyx 19-23.jpg-Distance[zyx 19-23.jpg]      3     0         19
9       3 zyx 19-23.jpg-Distance[zyx 19-23.jpg]      3     0         20
10      3 zyx 19-23.jpg-Distance[zyx 19-23.jpg]      3     0         21
11      3 zyx 19-23.jpg-Distance[zyx 19-23.jpg]      3     0         22
12      3 zyx 19-23.jpg-Distance[zyx 19-23.jpg]      3     0         23
13      4       zyx 24.jpg-Distance[zyx 24.jpg]      4     0         24
14      5 zyx 25-28.jpg-Distance[zyx 25-28.jpg]      1     0         25
15      5 zyx 25-28.jpg-Distance[zyx 25-28.jpg]      1     0         26
16      5 zyx 25-28.jpg-Distance[zyx 25-28.jpg]      1     0         27
17      5 zyx 25-28.jpg-Distance[zyx 25-28.jpg]      1     0         28
18      6       zyx 29.jpg-Distance[zyx 29.jpg]      2     0         29
19      7         zyx 3.jpg-Distance[zyx 3.jpg]      3     0          3
20      8 zyx 30-32.jpg-Distance[zyx 30-32.jpg]      4     0         30
21      8 zyx 30-32.jpg-Distance[zyx 30-32.jpg]      4     0         31
22      8 zyx 30-32.jpg-Distance[zyx 30-32.jpg]      4     0         32
23      9 zyx 33-36.jpg-Distance[zyx 33-36.jpg]      1     0         33
24      9 zyx 33-36.jpg-Distance[zyx 33-36.jpg]      1     0         34
25      9 zyx 33-36.jpg-Distance[zyx 33-36.jpg]      1     0         35
26      9 zyx 33-36.jpg-Distance[zyx 33-36.jpg]      1     0         36
27     10 zyx 37-43.jpg-Distance[zyx 37-43.jpg]      2     0         37
28     10 zyx 37-43.jpg-Distance[zyx 37-43.jpg]      2     0         38
29     10 zyx 37-43.jpg-Distance[zyx 37-43.jpg]      2     0         39
30     10 zyx 37-43.jpg-Distance[zyx 37-43.jpg]      2     0         40
31     10 zyx 37-43.jpg-Distance[zyx 37-43.jpg]      2     0         41
32     10 zyx 37-43.jpg-Distance[zyx 37-43.jpg]      2     0         42
33     10 zyx 37-43.jpg-Distance[zyx 37-43.jpg]      2     0         43
34     11 zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]      3     0         44
35     11 zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]      3     0         45
36     11 zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]      3     0         46
37     11 zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]      3     0         47
38     11 zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]      3     0         48
39     11 zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]      3     0         49
40     11 zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]      3     0         50
41     11 zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]      3     0         51
42     11 zyx 44-52.jpg-Distance[zyx 44-52.jpg]      3     0         52
43     12 zyx 53-54.jpg-Distance[zyx 53-54.jpg]      4     0         53
44     12 zyx 53-54.jpg-Distance[zyx 53-54.jpg]      4     0         54
45     13       zyx 55.jpg-Distance[zyx 55.jpg]      1     0         55
46     14 zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]      2     0         56
47     14 zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]      2     0         57
48     14 zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]      2     0         58
49     14 zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]      2     0         59
50     14 zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]      2     0         60
51     14 zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]      2     0         61
52     14 zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]      2     0         62
53     14 zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]      2     0         63
54     14 zyx 56-64.jpg-Distance[zyx 56-64.jpg]      2     0         64
55     15         zyx 6.jpg-Distance[zyx 6.jpg]      3     0          6
56     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0         65
57     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0         66
58     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0         67
59     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0         68
60     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0         69
61     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0         70
62     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0         71
63     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0         72
64     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0         73
65     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0         74
66     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0         75
67     16 zyx 65-76.jpg-Distance[zyx 65-76.jpg]      4     0         76
68     17   zyx 7-14.jpg-Distance[zyx 7-14.jpg]      1     0          7
69     17   zyx 7-14.jpg-Distance[zyx 7-14.jpg]      1     0          8
70     17   zyx 7-14.jpg-Distance[zyx 7-14.jpg]      1     0          9
71     17   zyx 7-14.jpg-Distance[zyx 7-14.jpg]      1     0         10
72     17   zyx 7-14.jpg-Distance[zyx 7-14.jpg]      1     0         11
73     17   zyx 7-14.jpg-Distance[zyx 7-14.jpg]      1     0         12
74     17   zyx 7-14.jpg-Distance[zyx 7-14.jpg]      1     0         13
75     17   zyx 7-14.jpg-Distance[zyx 7-14.jpg]      1     0         14
76     18 zyx 77-78.jpg-Distance[zyx 77-78.jpg]      2     0         77
77     18 zyx 77-78.jpg-Distance[zyx 77-78.jpg]      2     0         78
78     19 zyx 79-83.jpg-Distance[zyx 79-83.jpg]      3     0         79
79     19 zyx 79-83.jpg-Distance[zyx 79-83.jpg]      3     0         80
80     19 zyx 79-83.jpg-Distance[zyx 79-83.jpg]      3     0         81
81     19 zyx 79-83.jpg-Distance[zyx 79-83.jpg]      3     0         82
82     19 zyx 79-83.jpg-Distance[zyx 79-83.jpg]      3     0         83
83     20 zyx1_ 4-5.jpg-Distance[zyx1_ 4-5.jpg]      4     0          4
84     20 zyx1_ 4-5.jpg-Distance[zyx1_ 4-5.jpg]      4     0          5
85     21 zyx2_ 4-5.jpg-Distance[zyx2_ 4-5.jpg]      1     0          4
86     21 zyx2_ 4-5.jpg-Distance[zyx2_ 4-5.jpg]      1     0          5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract with `str_match` and then use `seq` to fill in the numeric ranges.

```
library(tidyverse)

trip |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(extracted = pluck(str_match_all(Miles, "\\[\\w+ (.*).jpg\\]"), 1, 2),
         filled = ifelse(str_detect(extracted, "-"), 
                         map(str_split(extracted, "-"), as.numeric) |> 
                           map(\(values) seq(values[[1]], values[[2]])), 
                         list(as.numeric(extracted)))) |> 
  unnest_longer(filled)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 86 × 6
   Meters Miles                                 Wheels Empty extracted filled
    <dbl> <chr>                                  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
 1      1 zyx 1-2.jpg-Distance[zyx 1-2.jpg]          1     0 1-2            1
 2      1 zyx 1-2.jpg-Distance[zyx 1-2.jpg]          1     0 1-2            2
 3      2 zyx 15-19.jpg-Distance[zyx 15-19.jpg]      2     0 15-19         15
 4      2 zyx 15-19.jpg-Distance[zyx 15-19.jpg]      2     0 15-19         16
 5      2 zyx 15-19.jpg-Distance[zyx 15-19.jpg]      2     0 15-19         17
 6      2 zyx 15-19.jpg-Distance[zyx 15-19.jpg]      2     0 15-19         18
 7      2 zyx 15-19.jpg-Distance[zyx 15-19.jpg]      2     0 15-19         19
 8      3 zyx 19-23.jpg-Distance[zyx 19-23.jpg]      3     0 19-23         19
 9      3 zyx 19-23.jpg-Distance[zyx 19-23.jpg]      3     0 19-23         20
10      3 zyx 19-23.jpg-Distance[zyx 19-23.jpg]      3     0 19-23         21
11      3 zyx 19-23.jpg-Distance[zyx 19-23.jpg]      3     0 19-23         22
12      3 zyx 19-23.jpg-Distance[zyx 19-23.jpg]      3     0 19-23         23
13      4 zyx 24.jpg-Distance[zyx 24.jpg]            4     0 24            24
14      5 zyx 25-28.jpg-Distance[zyx 25-28.jpg]      1     0 25-28         25
15      5 zyx 25-28.jpg-Distance[zyx 25-28.jpg]      1     0 25-28         26
```